# atomchace function in biojava

Tags: java, netbeans, biojava

Hi everyone I'm fairly new to biojava and trying to implement this piece of code:

```
AtomCache cache = new AtomCache();
cache.setPath("/tmp/");
FileParsingParameters params = cache.getFileParsingParams();
params.setLoadChemCompInfo(true);
StructureIO.setAtomCache(cache);
Structure strucuture = StructureIO.getStructure("4HHB");
```

after executing these lines im getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: lineSplit
>     at org.biojava.bio.structure.align.util.UserConfiguration.(UserConfiguration.java:87)
>     at org.biojava.bio.structure.align.util.AtomCache.(AtomCache.java:115)
>     at protein_structure.main(protein_structure.java:27)
>   Java Result: 1

I cant figure out the reason for this error, I downloaded the pdb files for the proteins that Im working with (in this case "4HHB" in the /tmp/ directory but still the same error is showing up. can anyone tell me how Atomcache function works? Thanks

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/109943/